# 12.04, Bizhub C360, job successful, but does not print, should require authentification

Tags: printing

I am trying to print to a network printer (Konica Minolta Bizhub C360).

I installed the printer with the driver supplied as the ppd:

```
KOC360UX.ppd
```

The protocol is JetDirect. Everything worked fine and the status information (Toner levels etc.) of the printer is visible.

But, when I print a test page the job finishes with status successful (in under a second). In the printers job history it says: "Deleted Due To Error".

Authentication is required (I know that from my windows using colleagues), but I am not asked for credentials.

So I assume that the printer expects the credentials to be delivered immediately. There is no obvious option to supply the login information though.

Maybe it is possible to add them to the printers URI? The current URI reads:

```
socket://10.162.183.136:9100
```

Furthermore, in the printing options under the tab "Job" one can add key value pairs. I tried with user = X and password = X. But it did not work.

Is there any way to make this work?

If you need more info, I'll supply.

Edit: I am now printing from my Windows VM, which is obviously a bad solution. But there I have to enter department and password. Maybe that is a hint for the required parameter in Ubuntu.